# Gridview Cannot get value control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to get the value for of a hiddenfield if a checkbox is checked on my gridview

my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_enfant" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        Width="533px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxenfant" runat="server"  />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="codeenfant" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("codeEnfants") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
               ..............
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is how I loop trhough the rows and check:

```
string myid = string.Empty; 
for (int i = 0; i < gv_enfant.Rows.Count; i++) 
{ 
    CheckBox chbox = (CheckBox)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant"); 
    if (chbox.Checked) 
    { 
        myid = ((HiddenField)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("codeenfant")).Value; 
    } 
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the condition, debugger never hit that line

Comment: Where (at what point of page life cycle) are you running this code?

Comment: @Andrei at a buttonClick event, I run the code

Comment: Are you forcing the gridview data binding at some point of time? If yes, can you show this code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all rows have the controls (e.g. The header and footer rows). I would try like this:

```
string myid = string.Empty; 
for (int i = 0; i < gv_enfant.Rows.Count; i++) 
{ 
    var chbox = gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant") as CheckBox; 
    var codeenfant = gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("codeenfant") as HiddenField
    if(chbox != null && codeenfant  != null)
    { 
        if (chbox.Checked) 
        { 
            myid = codeenfant.Value; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Good.  Better to filter on RowType.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
string myid = string.Empty;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvShows.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chk = row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
    {
        myid = ((HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("codeenfant")).Value;
    }
}
```

Regards